# Rails create / update join table with additional field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activerecord

**JOIN TABLE**

- Category (foreign key)
- Product (foreign key)
- Rank (integer)

Each time I create/update time join table I have to inser the rank position.

**Model**

```
class Category < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :products

class Product < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :categories
```

**Schema.db**

```
create_table "products_categories", id: false, force: :cascade do |t|
    t.bigint "category_id", null: false
    t.bigint "product_id", null: false
    t.integer "rank"
    t.index ["category_id", "product_id"], name: "index_products_categories_on_category_id_and_product_id"
  end
```

I know I can do this. But how can I pass the rank value ?

```
c = Category.find(1)
c.products = array_of_products
c.save
```

**Rails 5.2**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As [@Sean](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1693169/sean) described, you need to use a `has_many :through` association since:

> You should use `has_many :through` if you need validations, callbacks or extra attributes on the join model.
>   [2.8 Choosing Between has_many :through and has_and_belongs_to_many](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-has-many-through-and-has-and-belongs-to-many)

For example, to create a join model `rank` (I can`t come up with a better name than rank, sorry!):

```
# join table migration
class CreateRanks < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :ranks do |t|
      t.references :product
      t.references :category
      t.integer    :rank

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Your models:

```
# product.rb
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :ranks
  has_many :categories, through: :ranks
end

# rank.rb 
class Rank < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :category
end

# category.rb
class Category < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :ranks
  has_many :products, through: :ranks
end
```

So you can create your records "in bulk" as follows:

```
Rank.create [
  { category: a, product: x, rank: 1},
  { category: b, product: y, rank: 2}
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a `has_many :association, through: :through_association` with an explicit model as the join model. That way you can store data about the association itself.

Comment: Ok, I got it. How can I insert/update records in bulk? 
eg. [{category: A, product: X, rank: 1}, {category: A, product: Y, rank: 2}, ..]